# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest using SmartCard authentication or existing authorization data

Tags: powershell, active-directory, smartcard

Till now i used to use Invoke-WebRequest as followed:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -u $url -header $header
```

while `$header` contains encoded username and password.

Since the web-site moved to work with Active Directory, smart card data is now used to authorize access

How can i use `Invoke-WebRequest` with smart card credentials ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SmartCards is basically treated the same as a website that needs a certificate.

I use the below code to download files from SharePoint with SmartCard authentication, you'd just need to modify `Invoke-WebRequest` to meet your requirements.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security

# Filtering for cert requirements...
$ValidCerts = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2[]](dir Cert:\CurrentUser\My | where { $_.NotAfter -gt (Get-Date) })

# You could check $ValidCerts, and not do this prompt if it only contains 1...
$Cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI]::SelectFromCollection(
    $ValidCerts,
    'Choose a certificate',
    'Choose a certificate',
    'SingleSelection'
) | select -First 1

$WebRequestParams = @{
    Uri = $Url       # Uri to file to download
    OutFile = $Path  # Path to where file should be downloaded (include filename)
    Certificate = $Cert
}
Invoke-WebRequest @WebRequestParams
```

Comment: Hi,  tryed it,  somehow its not working...  I still recieving response that i sent wrong credentials 